# How to pass variable from module back to script?

Tags: function, powershell, module

I have noticed that variables inside a module function do not remain in scope after execution returns to the script. I came across `Export-ModuleMember` but that didn't seem to help, perhaps i'm using it wrong.

FunctionLibrary.psm1

```
Function AuthorizeAPI
{
   # does a bunch of things to find $access_token
   $access_token = "aerh137heuar7fhes732"
}
Write-Host $access_token
aerh137heuar7fhes732

Export-ModuleMember -Variable access_token -Function AuthorizeAPI
```

Main script

```
Import-Module FunctionLibrary

AuthorizeAPI # call to module function to get access_token

Write-Host  $access_token 
# nothing returns
```

I know as an alternative I could just dot source a separate script and that would allow me to get the access_token but I like the idea of using modules and having all my functions therein. Is this doable? Thanks SO!

Comment: `$access_token =` -> `$script:access_token =`

Comment: Hm, that didnt work. Variable is still empty when execution returns to Main script

Comment: Variable empty or not exists?

Comment: How do I tell the difference?

Comment: I also notice the module doesn't seem to execute the Export-ModuleMember line. After the function has finished it just returns to the main script

Comment: Wouldn't `$script:access_token` just make it available within the script that its defined (the module) ? Perhaps I need, `$global:access_token` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @PetSerAl's comment, you can change the scope of your variable. Read up on scopes [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh847849.aspx). `script` scope did not work for me when running from console; `global` did.

```
$global:access_token = "aerh137heuar7fhes732"
```

Alternatively, you can return the value form the function it  and store in a variable; no scope change needed.

**Function**

```
Function AuthorizeAPI
{
   # does a bunch of things to find $access_token
   $access_token = "aerh137heuar7fhes732"
   return $access_token
}
```

**Main Script**

```
Import-Module FunctionLibrary

$this_access_token = AuthorizeAPI # call to module function to get access_token

Write-Host  $this_access_token
```